# Shared Memory Key Overflow

Tags: c#

I am using a third party library that uses a C# DLL to access resources which in turn uses memory mapping to a C++ runtime. This third party is SkypeKit which is no longer under development.

Out of the blue, I received an exception (application ran for days) `"Shared Memory Key Overflow"`. The stack trace does not provide any of my routines so that I can catch it where it happens and fix it on the fly, and I'm currently cathing it in App code behind as an end all approach to catch exceptions and gracefully recover the application.

**Is there any way to handle this memory issue when it is caused outside of my code, or a way to analyze it more to find out why it happened?**

Cheers.

**Stack Trace**

> 6/12/2014-6:47:54 PM: DEBUG: Stack traceSystem.Exception: Shared
>   memory key overflow. The memory does not want to be shared.   at
>   SkypeKit.SharedMemoryChannel.CreateMapping(UInt32 size)   at
>   SkypeKit.FrameTransport..ctor()   at SkypeKit.SktVideoRenderer.Start()
>   at SkypeKit.SktVideoRenderer.TimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback,
>   Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)   at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)   at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback,
>   Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)   at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()   at
>   A.c8b9966635edfd27b3cf3481492785b16.Configurator_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e)   at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)   at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler,
>   Object target)   at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)   at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)   at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object
>   source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)   at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)   at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)   at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()   at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)   at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)   at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)   at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)   at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)   at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)   at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback,
>   Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)   at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)   at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()   at CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Object )   at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)   at (Object , CallSite , Object )   at
>   A.c7f72f7dfd341bf9a74e5c8753c372d7b.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)

Comment: Post all exception details. Maybe they allow to know more about the cause of the exception.

Comment: Appended stack trace.